# Problems with deploy Nuxt.js project on GitHub Pages

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a project:
https://github.com/merrymaker14/vuegl

I decided to upload to GitHub Pages:
https://merrymaker14.github.io/vuegl

But he does not go through the pages normally, although he seems to have set everything up. Why?
I did everything according to the official documentation.

nuxt.config.js:

````
/* nuxt.config.js */
// only add `router.base = '/<repository-name>/'` if `DEPLOY_ENV` is `GH_PAGES`
const routerBase = process.env.DEPLOY_ENV === 'GH_PAGES' ? {
  router: {
    base: '/vuegl/'
  }
} : {}

export default {
  mode: 'universal',

  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: pkg.name,
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: pkg.description }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#fff' },

  ...routerBase,

  router: {
     middleware: 'pages',
     //base: '/examples/vuegl/'
  },

  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
  ],

  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [
  ],

  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
  ],

  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend(config, ctx) {
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: it dont seem that your router base is set. Did u set it during build time?

Comment: No. By the way, animation component (there's Three.js) also doesn't work.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FX9Lw.png - that's weird.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rehEt.png

Answer (score 6):

I was running into the same problem, here's what I did to solve it.

1. Add to `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
  // Allows page refresh to work on github pages
  generate: {
    fallback: "404.html"
  },
```

2. Add a blank file `.nojekyll` to the `static/` directory (*prevents github building it as a Jekyll site*)
3. When deploying you will need to do `gh-pages -d dist -t true` (*as the default deployment ignores files starting with '.'*)

### Why this works

There's several problems that the above solution solves.

1. adding `fallback: "404.html"`, this allows *SPA*'s (single page applications) to work on Github Pages.

   1. Any route like `example.github.io/my-nuxt-app/some/page` will redirect to the custom `404.html` file, which will keep the SPA loaded. [more info here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/creating-a-custom-404-page-for-your-github-pages-site)
2. `.nojekyll` prevents github building it as a Jekyll site, Github automatically thinks a gh-pages site is a Jekyll site if it has a `/pages` directory
3. `gh-pages -d dist -t true` is required so that the `.nojekyll` file is actually deployed to Github Pages, as by default the `gh-pages` command ignores files starting with `.`

Comment: Hi, Ben! Thank you. Could you explain why it works? It helped me in the same situation. I don't think .nojekyll is the main problem?

Comment: Added some more explanation, there's actually 3 problems that this solution solves...